# STM32CubeIDE doesn't generate configuration code (NUCLEO-H745ZI)

Tags: stm32

I'm new to STM microcontrollers and trying to use the STM32CubeIDE.
The problem is that it doesn't generate the codes that configure the GPIO registers.

More specifically, I'd like to set the PB14 as an output port so that the LED3 can blink.

[image: Here's the screenshot.]

After this screen, in my understanding, the code to configure PIO registers should be automatically generated in main.c, whether it's for the Cortex-M4 core or M7. However, there was nothing like that. Even the global search for such a code didn't find one. As a result, the code below, which is supposed to toggle the output level for the LED3, just don't work. (It didn't blink.)

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_SET);
HAL_Delay(1000);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
HAL_Delay(1000);
```

When I manually set the registers as shown below, the LED3 successfully blinks.

```
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
GPIO_InitStructure.Pin   = GPIO_PIN_14;
GPIO_InitStructure.Mode  = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.Pull  = GPIO_NOPULL;
GPIO_InitStructure.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);
```

I'm using the NUCLEO-H745ZI board.

---

***Edit:***

Solved.

For MCUs that have multiple cores, I just had to select the core that I want to put the generated code in, as shown below.
[image: correct setting]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the project configuration tab? (and please add it as a picture instead of a link to the picture)

Comment: *`When I manually set the registers as shown below`* you did not set any registers. You just called HAL function

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to see my question. I noticed that I had to set **Pin context assignment** on the center of the screenshot to whichever of the cores, *Arm Cortex-M4* or *Arm Cortex-M7*, that I want to put the setting code in, and that worked.

Comment: @P__J__ that is quite pedantic of you. The HAL will set the registers, as such the registers are set to the correct values.

Comment: @ushi please add your own answer with an explanation of what you've done so you can close your question by accepting your answer. Comments aren't guaranteed to be kept and don't make clear to others what the solution to your (their) question is.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Tarick Welling. I added the screenshot to clarify the solution. I also learned how to to add an in-line picture from your edit.